# C# events, what's with that null thing?

Tags: c#, events

I can't really understand what is this null testing thing for when raising an event.

Say i have this code.

```
    class ballClass
{


    public event EventHandler BallInPlay;


    public void onHit()
    {
        if (BallInPlay != null)
        {
            BallInPlay(this, new EventArgs());
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("null!");
        }
    }



}
```

and I want to to raise a BallInPlay even when the onHit() method is triggered.

right now it shows me that the BallInPlay IS null. how or with what should i "fill" it for it to work?

Thanks!

Comment: If you don't like this null-check, then `event EvtType Name = delegate {};` will ensure that the event delegate object well, exists. Events are like other (reference) properties in that they default to null. They are different than other properties in that a `+=` will create a new event delegate if it doesn't exist -- nice magic considering the default. I imagine having it default to null is an optimization for only needing objects for events which have a handler installed, although I'm not sure if the event object (generally a MulticastDelegate) will "go away" if all handlers are removed :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to *subscribe* to the event with a handler. For example:

```
BallClass ball = new BallClass();
ball.BallInPlay += BallInPlayHandler;
// Now when ball.OnHit is called for whatever reason, BallInPlayHandler
// will get called
...
private void BallInPlayHandler(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // React to the event here
}
```

For more information, you may want to read my [article on events and delegates](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter2/Events.aspx).

Note that I've fixed the casing of `BallClass` and `OnHit` above - it's a good idea to use the standard .NET naming conventions to make your code fit in better with the code around it, and to make it more readable for others.

One thing to note: the nullity check you've got at the moment isn't thread-safe. The last subscriber could unsubscribe *after* the `if` but before the invocation. A thread-safe version would be:

```
public void OnHit()
{
    EventHandler handler = BallInPlay;
    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler(this, new EventArgs());
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("null!");
    }
}
```

This wouldn't be guaranteed to use the latest subscribers (as there's no memory barrier involved) but it *is* guaranteed not to throw a NullReferenceException due to race conditions.

Comment: @Rob: I think it's more important for you to read articles to make everything clear in your mind, not just use the pasted codes and make your current program working.

Answer (score 10):

The thing here is that if zero listeners are registered to listen to this event get raised, the event is null. If one or more listeners are registered it will have a value.

That means that if zero listeners are registered, and you try to raise the event without performing the null check, your program will throw an exception.

Comment: +1 - aka ... else { MessageBox.Show("No subscribers to this event"); }

Comment: If all handlers are removed does the event once again become null? This answer makes it sounds like that is the case.

Comment: @pst: It does actually.  I just checked.

Comment: @pst: As Jeff M have confirmed it does. That also mean that you can set the event to null yourself to remove all handlers from the event (this is only allowed to be done from inside the class that own the event). Also, the event has a InvocationList that contains the list of all handlers that are attached to the event, and you can invoke them manually. Useful if you only want to invoke some handlers, or if you care about the return value from all the handlers. If you invoke the event in the "normal" way, only the return value from the last handler is returned.

Answer (score 2):

The null test is ther because if NOONE IS LISTENING to the event, the event object that you swuold call is actually null.
So, without subscribers you would get a null pointer exception.

Answer (score 2):

If there are no event handlers assigned to the event, the event is null. Think of an event like a List, when there are no items in the list the value of the event becomes `null`.

Attempting to invoke the event **when there are no event handlers assigned to it will raise a NullReferenceException.**

The null check prevents the NullReferenceException.

If you want BallInPlay to work you need to add an `EventHandler`.

Your code will be something like this:

`BallInPlay += new EventHandler(YourFunctionNameGoesHere);`

Answer (score 1):

The null test is to determine whether or not anything is listening to the event.  Once something attaches an event handler, BallInPlay will no longer be null

Answer (score 1):

```
BallInPlay(this, new EventArgs());
```

The reason for the `null` check before triggering the event will become obvious once you realise that the above line of code actually gets compiled as if you had written the following:

```
BallInPlay.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
//        ^^^^^^^
```

And as we all know, it's a bad idea to call a method on a `null` reference. That's why you need to check that `BallInPlay != null` first.

---

**Additional suggestions:**

- Use [**`EventArgs.Empty`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventargs.empty.aspx) instead of `new EventArgs()`.
- You could get around the check for `null` if you initialized `BallInPlay` as follows:

  `public event EventHandler BallInPlay`**`= delegate { }`**`;`

  This works because now, there's always an "empty" handler method subscribed to this event. Thus you have a guarantee that the event delegate is no longer `null` after initialization. (Some people might consider this slightly inefficient.)

  You can always subscribe or unsubscribe event handlers with the `+=` or `-=` operators on the `BallInPlay` event; for example:

  `ball.BallInPlay += (sender, e) => { /* react to the triggered event */ };`
- I think **your `onHit`** (or, rather, `OnHit` if we're adhering to the usual conventions found in the .NET world) **method should not be public**, because this counters the whole purpose of events. Events are actually delegates, but with some added restrictions. One such restriction is that only the class defining the event can invoke ("trigger") it. Delegates, on the other hand, can be invoked by anyone. Thus, if you make `onHit` public, thereby allowing anyone to trigger your event, you could just as well have defined `BallInPlay` as a delegate, i.e. without the `event` keyword.
- A **thread-safe** implementation of your `onHit` event trigger method is shown below. Note that a local copy of the event handler delegate is used inside the method. This is to make sure that the event handler won't be modified (e.g. by another thread) between the check for `null` and the invocation.

---

```
protected virtual void OnHit()
{
    EventHandler handler = BallInPlay;  // use a local copy of the event
    if (handler != null)                // for better thread-safety!
    {
        handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
BallInPlay += new EventHandler(myFunc);

public void myFunc(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
MessageBox.Show("Woho \o/");
}
```